# Jmeter counter function value to be displayed in Benashell Post Processor or sampler

Tags: function, jmeter, counter, display, beanshell

And I would like to evaluate i.e.

```
 ${productId_1} 
 ${productId_2}
```

It should be as simple as:

```
${__V(productId${counter})}
```

Same approach applies to __counter() function:

```
${__V(productId_${__counter(,)})}
```

How can I display the value in Beanshell processor/sample instead of the thread name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how one can display or use the counter function value or counter in conjunction with variable
I am using this inside the Beanshell sample under the for each controller

Product = vars.get("Product_" + ${__counter(,)});

//save counter value into variable

counter = ${__counter(,)};
log.info("Counter ="+counter);

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

- For `counter`: `vars.get("counter")`
- For `productId_${counter}`: `vars.get("productId_" + vars.get("counter"))`

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Counter]

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity. See A[pache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more details if needed.