# JMeter for each controller - beanshell sampler display multiple variables

Tags: foreach, controller, jmeter, beanshell

I have JSON Request where multiple products nodes returns from there I am using product SKU inside the for each controller as input and sku_value as output which I am using in subsequent request.
Inside this for each controller I have another beanshell sampler where I would like print/display to use other values returns by first JSON request i tried this
[Jmeter counter function value to be displayed in Benashell Post Processor or sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508382/jmeter-counter-function-value-to-be-displayed-in-benashell-post-processor-or-sam) 
vars.get("productId_" + vars.get("counter")) but it return NULL 
if I use ${__V(productId_${__counter(TRUE,)})} at the sampler name it correctly prints the value but i want this value to printed using log.info
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that `${counter}` variable exists and has valid numeric value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination

If your `${__V(productId_${__counter(TRUE,)})}` works fine you can just use it in Beanshell Sampler's "Parameters" section and refer the value as `Parameters` in the script:

[image]

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity.

Comment: this display the value correctly but now I am facing a problem where the counter doesn't reset 1 its just keep incrementing by 1 even for 2nd input value in for each controller. Although the actual original input value to for each loops through all the correct variables but since I am trying to access the different variable than the one passed in to the for each controller